# Show that $\mathfrak{Z}$ is a semi ring

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> > Consider measurable spaces $(\Omega_t,\mathcal{A}_t), t\in T$ ($T$ is any index set). With $\mathcal{E}(T)$ we the set of all finite, not-empty subsets of $T$. Show that 
> >     $$
> > \mathfrak{Z}:=\mathfrak{Z}(\mathcal{A}_t: t\in T):=\bigcup_{S\in\mathcal{E}(T)}\underbrace{\left\{\times_{t\in T}A_t: A_t\in\mathcal{A}_t, t\in S; A_t=\Omega_t, t\in T\setminus S\right\}}_{=:\mathfrak{K}_S}
> > $$
> >     is a semi ring.

The first thing I have to show is that $\emptyset\in\mathfrak{Z}$. To show this just take any $S\in\mathcal{E}(T)$ and choose $A_t=\emptyset$ for a $t\in S$.

The second thing I have to show is, that for $x,y\in\mathfrak{Z}$ it is $x\cap y\in\mathfrak{Z}$. I think, that's easy, too:

Assume that $x,y\in\mathfrak{Z}$. Then there is a $S_1\in\mathcal{E}(T)$ so that $x\in \mathfrak{K}_{S_1}$ and a $S_2\in\mathfrak{E}(T)$ so that $y\in \mathfrak{K}_{S_2}$. Then $S_1\cup S_2\in\mathcal{E}(T)$ and $x\cap y\in\mathfrak{K}_{S_1\cup S_2}\in\mathfrak{Z}$.

The last thing to show is the most difficult one for me. It is to show that for $x,y\in\mathfrak{Z}, x\subset y$ there are finite many disjoint sets $c_1,\ldots c_n$ so that
$$
y\setminus x=\biguplus_{k=1}^{n} c_k.
$$
Do not really know how to show that.

My first idea is:

If $x,y\in\mathfrak{Z},x\subset y$, then there is a $S\in\mathcal{E}(T): x,y\in\mathfrak{K}_S$.

Let $y$ be $y=\times_{t\in T}A_t$ with $A_t\in\mathcal{A}_t$ for $t\in S$ and $A_t=\Omega_t$ for $t\in T\setminus S$ and $x$ be $x=\times_{t\in T}B_t$ with $B_t\in\mathcal{A}_t$ if $t\in S$ and $B_t=\Omega_t$ if $t\in T\setminus S$.

Then to my understanding it is
$$
y\setminus x=\times_{t\in T}C_t, C_t=B_t\setminus A_t, t\in S; C_t=\Omega_t, t\in T\setminus S.
$$

But now I do not know how to write this as a disjoint union of sets $c_1,\ldots c_n$.

---

Would be great to here if my recent results are allright and then to get some help to end the third necessary thing.

With greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you previous results are correct. For the third thing, let $S:=\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}$ be such that $X,Y\in \mathcal R_S$. We can write 
$$Y\setminus X=\bigsqcup_{i=1}^n\times_{t\in T}A_t^{i},$$
where 
$$A_t^i=\begin{cases}
\Omega_t&\mbox{ if }t\notin S;\\
\Omega_t\setminus A_t&\mbox{ if } t=s_i\mbox{ for some }i\in [n];\\
A_t&\mbox{ if }t\in S\setminus \{s_i\}.
\end{cases}$$